# Content is overriding my footer - Want a fixed or Max height

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the body of my content to scroll / have a definitive height. I have tried max- and min-height but I dont know what it is in my CSS that is making the content scroll to the bottom.

Site: https://go.trustradius.com/TriNet_TriNet-Vertical-Page-COPY.html

Min-height, max-height, adjusting page height. etc.

body>

```
<div id="tqaAllInOne" style="width: 90%;height:500px;margin: auto; padding:50px 0px;
">

    <div id="TQAobject" style="width:20%;min-width:250px;min-</height:400px;display:inline-block;position:absolute;margin-left:15px;border: 1px solid #ccc;background-color:white;">
        <div style="z-index: 100; background-color: white;">
            <div id="blurbContainer" style=" height: ; padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 70px;">
                <h3 style="position:relative; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;padding: 0px;line-height: 1em;font-size: 1.3em;font-family: inherit;font-weight: 600;">Selected Quote</h3>
                <div id="blurbText" onclick="copyText()" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: inherit;font-weight: 300;line-height: 1.4em;color: #444;text-decoration: none;text-size-adjust: none;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;padding-bottom:20px;text-shadow: none;cursor: pointer;text-align: left;">Select a TrustQuote you would like to copy</div>
                    <button onclick="copyText()" style="position: absolute;bottom: 20px;left: 20px;right: 20px;top: 20px; font-family: serif;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 300;padding: 3px 8px;margin: 0px;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 0px;min-height: 35px;max-width: 300px;top: auto;background-color: #ecf4ff;color: #002269;">Copy Quote to Clipboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: that not work because of child element have `1192px` height

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is fairly broad and a little unclear, which makes it difficult for us to help. You might want to learn about creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

That not working because of your child element have `fixed` height with `!important` and its specificity is also greater than your parent element, so your CSS not working atall in this situation.

If you can remove this height, your problem is solved, look out below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather add a comment but I can't because I don't have enough reputation.

When I remove the 'position: absolute' property of the class .lpeCElement (with my browser developer tools) then your site seems to behave like you want (scrollable content, not overlapping footer) without anything else broken.

Hope this helps.

See the attached picture :
[working site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Nly.png)